# How can I upload multiple image file and view them accordingly after upload by javascript as I've done in the code?

Tags: javascript

Here, when I upload the first image it appears in the third place and when I try to upload the second and third image it keeps appearing in the same place. The previous images become no longer available. But I have to upload all three images and appears them to the right places. How can I do it?

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
        var image = document.getElementById('output-1');
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var image2 = document.getElementById('output-2');
        image2.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
    var loadFile = function(event) {
        var image3 = document.getElementById('output-3');
        image3.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_one" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image One)</span></p>
  <p><img id="output-1" width="200" src=""/></p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_two" id="file"  onchange="myfunction()" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image Two)</span></p>
  <p><img id="output-2" width="200" src=""/></p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_three" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image Three)</span></p>
  <p><img id="output-3" width="200" src=""/></p>
</div>
```

Comment: please review your code ; you call `myfunction` but it's not defined ; you create 3 event handlers, but assign them to the same `loadFile` var... Can't see how it's supposed to work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to make label unique to input and call correct function

https://jsfiddle.net/nvcx2qmg/

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_one" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
      <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image One)</span></p>
      <p><img id="output-1" width="200" src=""/></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_two" id="file2"  onchange="loadFile2(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
      <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file2" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image Two)</span></p>
      <p><img id="output-2" width="200" src=""/></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_three" id="file3"  onchange="loadFile3(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
      <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file3" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image Three)</span></p>
      <p><img id="output-3" width="200" src=""/></p>
    </div
```

.

```
 function loadFile(event) {
    console.log("1")
      var image = document.getElementById('output-1');
      image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
    function loadFile2(event) {
    console.log("2")

      var image2 = document.getElementById('output-2');
      image2.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
     function  loadFile3(event) {
     console.log("3")

      var image3 = document.getElementById('output-3');
      image3.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works. But how can I take the files in different index of files[] ?                                                                                                                               
Like , image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);                                                 image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[1]);                                                    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[2]);

Answer (score 0):

You overrided function `loadFile` by defining it multiple times.
The problen could be solved by using different names or adding image id as an argument

```
var loadFile = function(event, imageId) {
  var image = document.getElementById(imageId);
  if (image) image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

also all ids must be uniq

```
<div class="form-group">
  <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_one" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output-1')" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image One)</span></p>
  <p><img id="output-1" width="200" src=""/></p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_two" id="file2" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output-2')" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file2" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image Two)</span></p>
  <p><img id="output-2" width="200" src=""/></p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="company_three" id="file3" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output-3')" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label class="btn btn-success" for="file3" style="cursor: pointer;">Change Logo</label> - <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">(Image Three)</span></p>
  <p><img id="output-3" width="200" src=""/></p>
</div
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wdfaLbur/